# How to run speech recognitaion (speech to text) in android device?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

Please any body know about speech recognition in android,
Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Can you please include the Android SDK and OS version - since the speech recognition support depends on the version?

From the question it is not clear if you want to develop a solution that invokes speech recognition or you want to invoke speech recognition as an end user.

If you are a developer and would like to invoke speech recognition tool in Android then you can have a look at example over here - [Speech Input](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html)

This is valid for Android 2.1 and above

If you are end user then refer to Android tutorials on how to use speech recognition.

Hope the information helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I am android developer. and i want to run application like speech to text. Means whatever we speak it will return as a text to speech. I know about TTS but how to recognize our speech.